# How to apt-get install in a GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: installation, github-actions, sudo, apt

In the new GitHub Actions, I am trying to install a package in order to use it in one of the next steps.

```yaml
name: CI

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  translations:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      with:
        fetch-depth: 1
    - name: Install xmllint
      run: apt-get install libxml2-utils
    # ...
```

However this fails with

```
Run apt-get install libxml2-utils
  apt-get install libxml2-utils
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
##[error]Process completed with exit code 100.
```

What's the best way to do this? Do I need to reach for Docker?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libxml2-utils`

Answer (score 422, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners) say:

> The Linux and macOS virtual machines both run using passwordless `sudo`. When you need to execute commands or install tools that require more privileges than the current user, you can use `sudo` without needing to provide a password.

So simply doing the following should work:

```
- name: Install xmllint
  run: sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-utils
```

Comment: it would be nice if someone could offer insight on _why_ this might be done...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: One explanation for `sudo: command not found` is that you created an environment variable named `PATH` in your action file overriding the system path used to locate commands. Ask me how I know...

Comment: not in this case though - I was using `act` for offline testing, and `act` apparently uses an image that doesn't _have_ sudo, and it's pretty nonsense (it's missing `lsb-release`, too, and a whoooole bunch of other things that make testing your github action basically meaningless)

Comment: `sudo` shouldn't be needed here.

Comment: @NavidKhan Without sudo: `Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)`

Comment: If you use just this line, without having the environment set to automatically confirm the installation, it won't work. Please consider editing to add `-y` option to `sudo apt-get install`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the heads up, I've been debating whether it would be worth my time to install and use `act` for the last few days.

Comment: @HashimAziz to be fair, that was in mid-2020, so check their docs instead of trusting me from three years ago.

Comment: Please consider using just `apt` instead of `apt-get`. Stone age is over

Answer (score 20):

Please see this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73500415/2038264

[cache-apt-pkgs-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/cache-apt-packages) can both install and cache the apt package, so your subsequent builds are fast. It is also easier to configure, just add the packages you want:

```yaml
      - uses: awalsh128/cache-apt-pkgs-action@latest
        with:
          packages: dia doxygen doxygen-doc doxygen-gui doxygen-latex graphviz mscgen
          version: 1.0
```

Comment: This is what dreams are made of.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is hinting the problem

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
```

Its a permission issue. So nice and simple, run it with sudo.

Sample example below

```
jobs:
  test:
    name: Unit test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: ⚙️ Install lcov
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get -y install lcov
```

Here the github action is installing `lcov` a tool to perform code coverage.