# Caching packages on GitHub action

Tags: caching, github-actions

In a GitHub Action workflow, I have

```
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
    sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
    sudo apt-get install nodejs
    sudo apt-get install yarn
```

To speed things up, I'd like to cache the installation so I don't have to install them every time I run the workflow (it's ok if the packages are not updated once a new version is released).

How can I use the `actions/cache@v2` to create a cache layer once the packages have been installed?

I have already checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269850/caching-apt-packages-in-github-actions-workflow) but I don't feel it answers my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use GitHub actions cache with brew install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63672189/use-github-actions-cache-with-brew-install)

Comment: I had the same problem, review my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65274407/1727383