# How expensive are github actions in terms of network traffic?

Tags: github-actions

one of the steps of my github test action for pull requests is installing 3rd party software via

```yaml
- name: Install imagemagick and graphviz
        run: |
          sudo apt install graphviz
          sudo apt install imagemagick
```

The package size seems to be about 15MB, see https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php. That's not too bad. But it made me wonder: if I installed a package of, say 500MB, would the github servers have to download the 500MB every time the action is triggered? That would be bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will download them each time, unless you will cache it. You can find more details here [Caching APT packages in GitHub Actions workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269850/caching-apt-packages-in-github-actions-workflow). You can also create your own docker image with pre installed packages and use that image in your pipeline. You will also find an example in above mention topic.